# 2 Questions - Responsive Design with Bootstrap & Fixed Arrow on the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

## 1) I currently have a "glyphicon" fixed on the bottom of the page, I am trying to have this icon fixed on the bottom corner when re-sizing the browser. As of now, it works when I am trying to re-size the browser width-wise, but it does not work height-wise. Does anyone know how to fix this? :P

## 2) This may require a longer answer :) I just don't understand why does it not work well on mobile... I tried on Iphone 6 & 4s; the 1st and last page image do not resize accordingly. Anyone has any good idea on why?

My site is kennylow.com.

My CSS File: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20432354/css/General.css
My HTML File: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20432354/index.html

Many thanks!

Kenny :)

Answer (score 0):

Your using 'absolute' positioning and referencing the 'top' property, for something like this it would be better to use position:fixed; which is relative to the Viewport, so it will always be at the bottom of the screen

```
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: 2em;
right: 2em;
z-index: 999;
```